# No changes made after modifying a source code of imported module in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to modify a source code of a module in node-modules folder. Simply, a problem is that I don't see any changes after modifying it. I tried with adding a word to see if changes are made properly but no changes at all.
I really want to know how to make changes to a source code of a module.

Comment: You'll probably want to fork the repo of the module and install your fork.

Comment: Is it just for debugging something? Maybe ng serve does not watch changes in node_modules folder

Comment: What I am trying to do is to add or modify functions in a calendar module that I import. I thought if I simply modified .ts file of the module, I could see some changes but it looked the same.

Comment: Hi, Brandon, Can you tell me about your comment in detail? that sounds  proper way but I don't know how to carry out those steps.